# Is there any way to use cache when sam building from launch.json?

Tags: python, debugging, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-toolkit

## The Problem

I am currently working in some **AWS Lambda Functions** and testing it **locally**. Usually, the command `sam build` takes a lot to finish, so I searched a way to optimize it and [found](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html) the `sam build --cached --user-container`.

When running it in the terminal, it works perfectly fine, creating the following folder structure:

```
2021-12-22 18:56:07 [INFO]: Preparing to debug locally: Lambda ""
2021-12-22 18:56:07 [INFO]: Building SAM application...
2021-12-22 18:56:08 [INFO]: Running command: (not started) [/usr/local/bin/sam build --build-dir /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkgHZxzf/output --template ./template.yaml --use-container --manifest /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkgHZxzf/debug-requirements.txt -u --cached]
2021-12-22 18:56:09 [INFO]: Starting Build use cache

2021-12-22 18:56:09 [INFO]: Starting Build inside a container

2021-12-22 18:56:10 [INFO]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.aws-sam/cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sam", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 157, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 122, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/cli/main.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 174, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/command.py", line 231, in do_cli
    with BuildContext(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/build_context.py", line 105, in __enter__
    self.set_up()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.36.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/commands/build/build_context.py", line 138, in set_up
    cache_path.mkdir(mode=BUILD_DIR_PERMISSIONS, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1292, in mkdir
    self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '.aws-sam'

2021-12-22 18:56:10 [WARN]: "sam build" failed
```

[Cache Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2OeA.png)

However, when I try to debug by using the `launch.json` in VSCode, it gives me this error:

**launch.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "Invoke Lambda: FunctionX",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "template",
            "templatePath": "template.yaml",
            "logicalId": "FunctionX",
        },
        "sam": {
            "containerBuild": true,
            "buildArguments": [
                "-u",
                "--cached",
            ]
        },
        "lambda": {
            "timeoutSec": 9999
        }
    }
]
```

}

So as you can see, the build fails when I try to debug it.

## What I Tried to Do

My first attempt was to manually input the cache directory adding the `--cache-dir` parameter:

**launch.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "Invoke Lambda: FunctionX",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "template",
            "templatePath": "template.yaml",
            "logicalId": "FunctionX",
        },
        "sam": {
            "containerBuild": true,
            "buildArguments": [
                "-u",
                "--cached",
                "--cache-dir",
                "${workspaceFolder}/.aws-sam/cache"
            ]
        },
        "lambda": {
            "timeoutSec": 9999
        }
    }
]
```

}

However, the same error keep happening. Then, I created a `samconfig.toml` file and configured by default the `sam build` command as `sam build -u --cached`. Still no effect.

In this context, I looked over GitHub Issues and Stack Overflow questions, but no one has ever had this kind of problem. It seems to me that no one tried to use the cache configuration with the launch.json, only by terminal running.

Could someone give me a hint if this is even possible to do, please?

Thanks in advance to everybody that reads and tries to help me!